# MBED Ticker doesn't attach interrupt

Tags: embedded, mbed

I have a class:

```
#ifndef _BUTTON_LISTENER_H_
#define _BUTTON_LISTENER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Buttons/MenuButton.h"
#include "MenuNavigator.h"

class MenuNavigator;

class ButtonListener
{
    public: 
        ButtonListener(MenuNavigator* navigator, unsigned int samplePeriod_us,
            MenuButton* select, MenuButton* down, 
            MenuButton* up, MenuButton* cancel);
        vector<MenuButton*> getButtons();
        MenuNavigator* getNavigator();
    protected:
        void init();
        void isr();
        vector<MenuButton*> buttons;
        MenuNavigator* navigator;
        unsigned int samplePeriod_us;
        Ticker ticker;
};

#endif
```

And its implementation:

```
#include "ButtonListener.h"
#include "Buttons/MenuButton.h"

ButtonListener::ButtonListener(MenuNavigator* navigator, 
    unsigned int samplePeriod, MenuButton* s, MenuButton* d, 
    MenuButton* u, MenuButton* c) : 
    navigator(navigator), 
    samplePeriod_us(samplePeriod_us)
{
    buttons.push_back(s);
    buttons.push_back(d);
    buttons.push_back(u);
    buttons.push_back(c);
    init();
}

void ButtonListener::init()
{
    ticker.attach_us(callback(this, &ButtonListener::isr), 500000);
}

void ButtonListener::isr()
{
    printf("in isr\n");
}
```

I'm attaching `isr()` method to create an interrupt so that it sends the text to the terminal window. But for some reason, it doesn't work.

If I put `printf()` statement before or after the `init()` method in the constructor, the text of `printf()` gets printed, but the text in the `isr()` doesn't.

Any help?

Comment: for the downvoters, do you mind explaining what you didn't like?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the problem, but in my experience class member functions must be static in order to be interrupt handlers.  (Think about it, the interrupt controller can't know which instance of the class to use.)  Also the `attach_us` function may require a C-style function pointer for the same reason (or maybe because of C++ name-mangling issues). Then from the C-style ISR function you can call the C++ static class member function.

Comment: @kkrambo, thanks for your answer. i accidentally found the reason for this. i'll put up an answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally found the solution. I have `MyClass` that instantiates `ButtonListener`. In this class, I declared `ButtonListener` as a pointer:

`ButtonListener* blistener;`.

In the constructor of the `MyClass`, I had `ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener(args...)`. After I changed it to just `buttonListener = new ButtonListener(args...)` things worked out.

Hope it's going to be helpful to someone else.